# Search function LINQ. Use checkbox values as parameters

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, search

I have a search function that tales 7 parameters and 6 of them are checkbox values. They are bools like shown down below. I Have a problem with my datetime search. If the user check that box if would like do run a serach function where that a date is not null in the database. My code look like this at the moment. But i would like to get some feedback to how to improve my code for better performance and code structure.

```
public List<Invoice> GetAllInvoicesBySearch(int merchant, long buyer, bool send, bool paid, bool firstReminder, bool secondReminder, bool invoiceClaim)
    {
        var sendValue = new InvoiceStatus();
        var paidValue = new InvoiceStatus();
        var firstRemind = new DateTime();
        var secondRemind = new DateTime();
        if (buyer <= 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (send)
        {
             sendValue = InvoiceStatus.Sent;
        }
        if (paid)
        {
            paidValue = InvoiceStatus.Paid;
        }
        if (firstReminder)
        {
            firstRemind = DateTime.Now;
        }
        if (secondReminder)
        {
            secondRemind = DateTime.Now;
        }

        return
            Context.Invoices.Where(
                i =>
                   i.InstallationId == merchant && i.Buyer.Msisdn == buyer || i.Status == sendValue || i.Status == paidValue ||
                    i.FirstReminderDate == firstRemind || i.SecondReminderDate == secondRemind).ToList();
    }
```

So my problem is with the datetime at the moment to get that correctly. Any suggestions on how to solve my problem and improve my code?

Comment: Change the `DateTime.Now` to `DateTime.Today` to skip the time part

Comment: Okey that solves one problem with the time. But my problem is that if a user checks a checkbox that it wants to search on date the search function doesn't works correctly. If a user checks that specific checkbox the query should get the invoices where the date is not null.

Comment: Add `&& i.SomeDate.HasValue` to get not null dates record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better off using a [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) and converting to an extension method like this:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods {
    public static IQueryable<Invoice> Search(this IQueryable<Invoice> src, int merchant,
        long buyer, bool send, bool paid, bool firstReminder,
        bool secondReminder, bool invoiceClaim)
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Invoice>();
        var sendValue = new InvoiceStatus();
        var paidValue = new InvoiceStatus();
        var firstRemind = new DateTime();
        var secondRemind = new DateTime();
        if (buyer <= 0)
        {
            return src.Where(predicate);
        }
        predicate=predicate.Or(i=>i.InstallationId == merchant && i.Buyer.Msisdn == buyer);
        if (send)
        {
             predicate=predicate.Or(i=>i.Status == InvoiceStatus.Sent);
        }
        if (paid)
        {
            predicate=predicate.Or(i=>i.Status == InvoiceStatus.Paid);
        }
        if (firstReminder)
        {
            predicate=predicate.Or(i=>i.FirstReminderDate == DateTime.Today);
        }
        if (secondReminder)
        {
            predicate=predicate.Or(i=>i.SecondReminderDate == DateTime.Today);
        }
        return src.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

Also, if I understand your code correctly, InvoiceStatus should either be an enum, or at the very least, InvoiceStatus.Sent and InvoiceStatus.Paid should be marked as being static.  Reference it like so:

`Context.Invoices.Search(...).OrderBy(...)...`

It will make further manipulation much easier if you need to do sorting, paging, filtering beyond the original searching.

Comment: Thank you, that was a really great tip. Thanks for improving my code!